# nav button click change style efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, processing-efficiency

My current code is too messy. Could you please help make it more efficient.

```
function buttons(){
    $('.notclicked').click(function(){
        $('.leftmenu').addClass('leftclicked');
        $('.mainwrap').addClass('mainclicked');
        $(this).removeClass('notclicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        $('.clicked').click(function(){
            $('.leftmenu').removeClass('leftclicked');
            $('.mainwrap').removeClass('mainclicked');
            $(this).removeClass('clicked');
            $(this).addClass('notclicked');
            buttons();
        });
        buttons();
   });
};
buttons();
```

As seen here. (http://quinnkeaveney.com/recondite/brian/index.php)

Comment: Unless you are having problems with your code, then this is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$(document).on('click', selector, function() {
  // your function
}
```

to bind clicks to selectors that may not have loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menu').click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    // find out if it has the notclicked class
    var notClicked = btn.hasClass('notclicked');
    // when notClicked is true, toggleClass acts like addClass
    // when notClicked is false, toggleClass acts like removeClass
    $('.leftmenu').toggleClass('leftclicked', notClicked);
    $('.mainwrap').toggleClass('mainclicked', notClicked);
    // This will toggle these both back and forth
    btn.toggleClass('notclicked clicked');
});
```